# How to get rid of error messages in Android when I run my updated NS 5.0 app?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to include all the angular features that speeds up the app for Android and iOS. The app compiles fine but when it boots, the app crashes. I recently updated my apps to Nativescript 5.0, once I run the app for debug mode for android,

```
tns run android --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot --env.snapshot
```

I see some Java/Android errors when the app loads:

```
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1116)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:996)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:983)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1116)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:996)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:983)
11-15 11:49:53.578 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
11-15 11:49:53.579 20598 20598 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
```

Same errors shows up when I try to run the Hello World app just created from scratch for production with the new `tns create` command in Nativescript 5.0.

I have the Android SDK up-to-date.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: what android sdk version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, a few things to check:

- run "tns docter"
- is everything fine? If not, solve the issues and/or try the steps below:

For me, it did not show any issues, still: next step is to make sure you have the right android sdk, android sdk build tools and android support repository installed:

I have the Android SDK installed with Eclipse, so I just launch the Android SDK Manager from there and installed:

- Android SDK Platform-tools 28.0.1
- Android SDK Build-tools 28.0.1 (THIS IS IMPORTANT, make sure it is exactly the same as the platform tools)
- Android 9 (28) / SDK Platform
- Extras / Android Support Repo
- Extras / Android Support Library

After this, I way able to built/run the app everytime (without --clean):

- tns platform remove android
- tns platform add android
- tns run android --bundle